# JQuery slide effect with bounce positioning issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create an effect which, on mouse over, slides out a div from the bottom of a parent div, and bounces once the slide is complete.

```
$("#testDiv").hover(function() {
    $(".box").stop().slideDown("slow", function() {
        $(".box").effect("bounce", {
            times: 3, distance: 3
        }, 250);
     });

    }, function() {
        $(".box").stop().slideUp();
});
```

A fiddle of my code so far is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/7TZ3E/

It sometimes seems to work, then it messes up in a number of different ways. Either it stops showing, jumps to the top of the parent div, or slowly decreases in size.

I'd appreciated any help to produce the effect I'm looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this will help you

```
$("#testDiv").hover(function(e) {
    $(".box").stop(true,true).animate({height: ['toggle',  'easeOutBounce']}, 'medium');
},
function(e) {
    $(".box").stop(true,true).animate({height: 'toggle'});

});​
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7TZ3E/22/) is a fiddle.

Comment: This still suffers from the problem that the black box's height gets smaller and smaller if one goes in and out of the blue box quickly. I think the problem here is that when calling stop on the animate, its seems to 'remember' the height of the black box the animation was stopped at, and continues on from there.

Comment: @Umair: That's right. I think it's better to handle box position with a boxcontainer div, and box slid normally in its container.

Comment: I think the black box is not getting smaller, it's always 30px when it's visible.

Comment: It will lose height when moving your mouse very quickly. Adding 'stop(true,true)' may helps. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7TZ3E/20/)

Comment: Updated and thanks but was it really smaller in height, may be it's an illusion because of bounce effect.

Comment: Yep adding stop(true,true) has fixed it! Nice.